# How to add multiple Objects to Array - Objective C / iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm new to programming in Objective C

Here is my Dilemma: I'm pulling in a JSON file from the web and I'm able to display one of the elements (currDate) to my tableView but now I want to display more. From the code below I would I get it to display both currDate and prevDate

**The logic needs to be changed here:**

```
for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) {
    NSString *currDate = [diction objectForKey:@"Current Date"];
    a = currDate;
    NSString *prevDate = [diction objectForKey:@"Previous Date"];
    b = prevDate;     

    [array addObject:a]; 

    }
    [[self myTableView]reloadData];
```

**I'm not sure if I need to change anything here but I'm attaching it to show how I'm displaying the array to my viewTable:**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [array count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.text = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: That for loop snippet is actually within this:

    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
    
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *feed= [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSArray *arrayOfEntry = [feed objectForKey:@"entry"];
....for...blah blah blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add another line:

```
[array addObject:a];
[array addObject:b];
```

Comment: yes that's what I did but program blows up when I do that and a SIGABRT error comes up on this line of code:

cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: How do you declare array in your .h file? Did you declare it as a strong property?

Comment: Actually, what I wrote in my comment might be wrong -- how is it that you want to present your data? Do you want currDate and prevDate in the same cell? You have to use a different cell type for that. Otherwise, you're just going to have alternating rows with currDate then prevDate, curate, prevDate, etc. which wouldn't be good.

Comment: Where and how is it defined then?

Comment: the latter (alternating rows)

Comment: Then I think what I wrote should work, if your array still exists by the time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called. I'll ask the question again. How and where do you declare array?

Comment: so i just declared my array globally following what the user in my other comment replied and the other items. now i'm not sure what to do with what's in my FOR statement.

Comment: What do you mean? What don't you know how to do?

Comment: where you told me to add the [array addObject:a];
[array addObject:b]; Do I need to make any changes in there?

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue, one addObject works fine but when at the second one (b) then it crashes

Comment: You need to update your post to show how and where you declare array, show how you updated your for-in loop, and try logging array to make sure it has in it what you think it should. Also in numberOfRowsInSection, log array.count to see what it gives.

Comment: Figured it out, it was a problem within the File that the program was reading. Your original suggestion worked perfectly, thanks again for taking the time to help out! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

make `arrayOfEntry` global. in .h file

```
NSArray *arrayOfEntry;
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
[arrayOfEntry count]
```

In `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *currDate = [[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Current Date"]
NSString *prevDate = [[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Previous Date"]
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %@", currDate, prevDate];
```

Comment: What should I do with my -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  where I have my for loop that I pasted above?

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple elements to an Array in objective c you need to use:

```
 NSMutableArray *newArr = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Then:

```
[newArr addObject:dict1];
```

If you want, you can then set your `NSArray` you were using to the `NSMutuableArray` after the addition of objects is complete.